# Verifying if indexes exist in a python multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, set

Checking on some code I see something like this:

```
// This snippet is from the variables display in VS code while debugging and psuedocode:
theIndex: (1, 1)
myDataa['aKeyPhrase'][a secondary group of arrays]
```

So the myData has a first index of 'aKeyPhrase' which is a variable that changes and is a unique string, like so:

```
aKeyPhrase = 'labelA'
aKeyPhrase = 'labelB', etc.
```

The second part of myData contains a set of numbers so `theIndex: (1, 1)` is referring to the first index and second index of the set:

```
// (1, 1) would be refering the numbers  24.0 and 18.0
{1: 24.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 34.0}
{1: 18.0, 2: 23.0, 3: 32.0}
```

Before I do anything the the myData I want to check if theIndex exists and if it is equal to '%' and do the following:

```
if theIndex not in myData[aKeyPhrase] or myData[aKeyPhrasel][theIndex] == '%':
```

The first part of that expression above is always `false`. It should be true since the indexes exist in the myData sample. How do I check this correctly?

Comment: could you show us a sample of `myData`?

Comment: It's the second part of myData which is sampled above in the (1, 1) with the numbers and such that I care about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, `theIndex` is a tuple and `myData[aKeyPhrase]` is a list of dictionaries and for `theIndex = (1, 2)`, 1 corresponds to the key of the first dict, and 2 is the key of the second dict, correct? In that case, in the if-condition, `if theIndex not in myData[aKeyPhrase]` will always return False. You could modify it as

```
if all(i in d for i, d in zip(theIndex, myData[aKeyPhrase])) or myData[aKeyPhrasel][theIndex] == '%'
```

Comment: I want something like this but am getting `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable` error

Comment: @cdub is `myData[aKeyPhrase]` type int or is it not a tuple of dictionaries? because we know `theIndex` is a tuple, right?

Comment: That appears to be correct

Comment: Yeah it's weird as theIndex is a list of int's to find the index and the myData[aKeyPhrase] has x number of lists and each of those lists contains ints as well.

Comment: I think yours is correct. There are more if clauses that are causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @cdub right. so is it resolved then? are you able to run your code?